# FluentMigrator issue with net8 AOT on MAUI for iOS

Tags: ios, maui, fluent-migrator, .net-8.0

We've been using FluentMigrator with Xamarin but now with `net8-ios` and with the new AOT compiler, seems like inclusion of all the runners in `FluentRunner.Runner` nuget package is causing AOT step to fail.

We get this error when running `dotnet publish -c Release -f net8.0-ios project.csproj`:

```
1>Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1211,3): Error  : Failed to AOT compile System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 134.
```

I know `FluentRunner.Runner` package references all other runners (SQLServerCE, Hana, ...).

Is there a way to only include those runners that are needed? In this case `SQLite` only?